# Laravel .htaccess error when uploaded to the host

Tags: laravel

Your .htaccess file like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
Options -MultiViews
</ IfModule>
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder ...
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}! -d
RewriteRule ^ (. *) / $ / $ 1 [L, R = 301]
# Handle Front Controller ...
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}! -d
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}! -f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond% {HTTP: Authorization}.
RewriteRule. * - [E = HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:% {HTTP: Authorization}]
</ IfModule>
```

Somehow the hosts to be up to 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: 500 errors mean something useful is sitting in your logs. The spaces in `</ IfModule>` look problematic. Laravel's .htaccess can be found at https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess

Comment: I already attempted to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The correct .htaccess should look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
  </IfModule>
  RewriteEngine On
  # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder ...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}! -d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/$/$1 [L,R=301]
  # Handle Front Controller ...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}! -d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}! -f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
  # Handle Authorization Header
  RewriteCond %{HTTP: Authorization}.
  RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
</IfModule>
```

You had too many spaces in the rules which broke them. Don't add any spaces to improve readability.

PS: Use a .htaccess validator like [www.htaccesscheck.com](http://www.htaccesscheck.com/) in the future and try to resolve the shown problems.